# How can I check if a variable is empty or undefined within an array using JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an array that I created but I would like to execute an action if one or more variables are empty in my array.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

        var fields = ["", "two", "three", "four", "five"];


        if (fields.length === 0) {
            alert('One or more variables are empty!');
        }

        else {
          alert('All variables are here!');
        }    


   });
```

I know this code above is wrong because it will always launch the latter.

So basically

```
var fields = ["", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
```

Should return **One or more variables are empty!**

And this:

```
 var fields = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
```

Should return **All variables are here!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?v=example). One thing that's nice about `every()` is that if a single element returns falsey, it will short-circuit the array iteration, meaning that it will not continue to unnecessarily process the remaining elements in the array.

```js
var fields = ["", "two", "three", "four", "five"]; // invalid array
var fields2 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]; // valid array

function validateFields (fields) {
  var everyFieldIsValid = fields.every(function (field) {
    // ensure there are no gaps in the array and that each element is not
    // undefined, null, or equal to empty string ("")
    return field != null && field !== "";
  }); 
  
  if (everyFieldIsValid) {
    // success logic goes here - you can console.log, alert, return true/false, etc.
    return "All variables are here!";
  }
  else {
    // failure logic goes here - you can console.log, alert, return true/false, etc.
    return "One or more variables are empty!";
  }
}

console.log(validateFields(fields));
console.log(validateFields(fields2));
```

Comment: A very simple solution. I never thought of this. Will try it now!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @Mariton Great! Glad to hear it =)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if every array element conforms to your condition using a function `Array.prototype.every`:

```js
var fields = ["", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

var res = fields.every(f => f != null && f.length) ? 'all here' : 'some are empty';

console.log(res)
```

`every(f => f != null && f.length)` checks if every element is defined, not equal to `null` and has length > 0. `res` is assigned an answer depending on this condition ([ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is used instead of `if` to make the code more clear).

Comment: "ternary operator is used instead of if to make the code more clear"... said no one ever...

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 fields.filter(function(object){
        return object.trim().length > 0;
    });
```

this will delete all the empty fields.
Simply add conditionnal if you want to know is there is a empty field!

Comment: This code makes a lot of assumptions.. `1. Assuming every element in the array is a string, and there are no "holes" in the array`, `2. Assuming the OP wants to remove the empty elements` I am pretty sure neither one of those assumptions are accurate, but you should ask the OP for clarification.